# effect of dying on the price of stuff ravio lends you

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

I just started Zelda: A Link Between Worlds and Ravio initially lent me a bow for free. I died and came back to life and then Ravio charged my 10 rupees. My question is...  what happens if I die again? Will I be charged 10 rupees again and for every subsequent death or does the amount Ravio charges go up each time?

Answer (score 2):

When you die, Ravio will take all lent items off your body. The "get this lent for free" sale is only temporary, **so when he gets the item back, it goes back to full price.** If you don't want to be charged 10 rupees each time you need the bow, just save up and buy it.

Comment: FYI Ravio only starts offering stuff for sale once you enter Lorule. Prior to that the only thing you can do is lease items from him. At the time I posted the question I was unaware of this.